# How to disable menu in jsf

Tags: javascript, jquery, jsf, menu

I want to disable the menu created inside my jsf page. Here is the code utilised for creating menu.

```
<div id="bloc_menu3">

    <ul class="sf-menu">
        <h:form>
            <li><a4j:commandLink value="#{label.ecran_corbeille}"
                    actionListener="#{queuesBean.resetQueuesListener}"
                    action="/queues/queues"
                    rendered="#{securityBean.corbeilleAccess and queuesBean.initOk}"
                    onclick="this.setAttribute('onclick', 'return false;');" /></li></h:form>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: You cannot 'disable' a div. That is technically impossible in html. How toi disable a menu depends on how you created it. See [ask] and [mcve] and [tour] and http://www.stackoverflow.com/tags/jsf/info

Comment: This is all plain html (if it works). Nothing jsf related here.

Comment: This menu I used as common menu. In one of my sub page i want to inactive this menu with grey color. I mean just for one of the subpage. That's my actual problem. Thank you for your quick reply.

Comment: It is a plain html UL, not any jsf thing or any menu. If you have some code that makes it a real menu, look at that code how to 'disable' this... Nothing JSF related here, nothing javascript or jquery. You'd have the same problem using a normal html form in there and a `<a href` tag instead of a ajax4jsf/richfaces commandLink